# How to make loop less messy and to function how it suppose to be

Tags: java, oop, netbeans

To cut a long story short, implementing a loop that allows the user to select the indexed value of the string element of the array and then return the selection to the user and validates user input.

The errors that i have noticed that the loop has an off by one error so included " <= " " | " .I have changed to an array initializer which can be less error-prone. The loop only just printed out the index values and not the string.   I have changed the array to array class and get the errors which are.   " Lesson constructor cannot apply to declared types, actual and form arguments differ in length " I have looked at the Javadoc declaration . and saw to declare within constructor such this. = new ArrayList(Length) or something like that but I do not want to overwrite anything. I have tried to get support in NetBeans to solve the issue but get the same error when I implement the code exactly what NetBeans support implement for the first element of the array

The loop code that I would like to function effectively

```
Lesson[] lessonList = new Lesson [4];


lessonList[0] =  new Lesson ("Zumba");
lessonList[1] = new Lesson("Spin");
lessonList[3] = new Lesson("Yoga");
lessonList[4] = new Lesson("BodySculpt");

for(int count = 0; count <= lessonList.length; | count++){
    System.out.println((count + 1) + ". " + lessonList[count]);
}

System.out.println("Please select ");
int selection = sc.nextInt();
selection -= 1;

if(selection >lessonList.length | selection < 0) {
    System.out.println(" You have entered invalued value.");
    lessonsList();
    System.out.println("Can you please re-enter selection  .");
} 

return selection;
```

error occurrence relates in the Lesson class with the constructor, Error  " Lesson constructor cannot apply to declared types, actual and form arguments differ in length "

```
public class Lesson {

    private String lessonTitle;
    private String lessonDate;
    private int lessonPrice;
    private Rating rating;

    public void Lesson (String title) {
        this.setTitle(title);
        rating = new Rating();
    }

    public void lesson (String zumba, 
                        String spin, 
                        String yoga, 
                        String bodysculpt ) 
    { 

        /// tried declaring recieve errors 
    }

    public Lesson() {
        this.lessonTitle = "Udentified";
        this.rating = new Rating();
    }
```

Expected results would be ironing out the flaws in the loop and basic solution hints for the constructor. so I can work on the next elements

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking.  Can you please [edit] and clarify?

Comment: `public void Lesson (String title)` is not a constructor but a `void` method with name `Lesson`. You need to remove the `void`

Comment: `lesson` != `Lesson`

Comment: `for (int count = 0; count < lessonList.length; count++) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                Lesson [] lessonList = new Lesson [4];
                lessonList[0] =  new Lesson ("Zumba", "Monday & Wednesday", 100, 3.4);
                lessonList[1] = new Lesson("Spin", "Tuesday & Thursday", 80, 3.9);
                lessonList[2] = new Lesson("Yoga", "Sunday", 83, 4.0);
                lessonList[3] = new Lesson("BodySculpt", "Friday and Saturday", 90, 3.85);


                for(int count = 0; count < lessonList.length; count++){
                    System.out.println((count + 1) + ". " + lessonList[count]); 
                }

                System.out.println("Please select between 1 - 4 for the lessons ");
                int selection = sc.nextInt();
                selection -= 1;
                while(selection >lessonList.length | selection < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Can you please re-enter selection  .");
                    selection = sc.nextInt();
                }
                System.out.println((selection + 1) + ". " + lessonList[selection]); 
    }
}

public class Lesson {

    private String lessonTitle;
    private String lessonDate;
    private double lessonPrice;
    private double rating;

    public Lesson() { //default constructor
        this.lessonTitle = null;
        this.lessonDate = null;
        this.lessonPrice = 0;
        this.rating = 0;
    }

    public Lesson (String title, String date, double price, double rate) { //second constructor
        this.lessonTitle = title;
        this.lessonDate = date;
        this.lessonPrice = price;
        this.rating = rate;
    }

**//When you want to print a class, you must need a toString method defined right**

    public String toString () {
        return "Lesson Title: " + this.lessonTitle + ", Lesson Date: " + this.lessonDate + ", $" + this.lessonPrice + ", Rate: " + this.rating;
    }

}
```